# Php mysql select month and year

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database there is a column which is employment_date in "Y/m/d" format, What I want is, select only year and month of employment_date. Following is the my DB query.

```
function checkDate($userID){
$res=mysql_query("Select YEAR (employment_date) AND MONTH(employment_date) from employee where emp_id='$userID'") or die("query error".mysql_error());
$array = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$value=$array['employment_date'];

echo("$value");
}
```

---

But Its not work, what is correct way to select month and year in my table, Please Help !

Comment: You have `Select` two times in your query

Comment: Two time select `Select Select` ??

Comment: Year and month in two separate columns or one?

Comment: no, the question is you want to extract year and month in separated columns or in one?

Comment: for month and date try this @Chathurika  SELECT MONTH(employment_date) AS 'month', DATE(employment_date) AS 'date'
FROM employee Where emp_id='$userID';

Comment: try my third answer for date  and month @Chathurika

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:-

```
// return month and date in single row
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `employment_date` ) 
FROM employee WHERE emp_id='$userID';
```

OR

```
// return month and date in two different row
SELECT YEAR(employment_date) AS 'year', MONTH(employment_date) AS 'month'
FROM employee Where emp_id='$userID';
```

**Warning**:-

> mysql_* functions are depracated and also removed from PHP7. So use
>   [mysqli_*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info) or better [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

Comment: If I want to select only month and date, How can I do it?

Comment: second query of my answer will give you only 'month' and 'date'. Are you facing any error?

Comment: Can you please post your code with second query in your question. I need to see query.

Answer (score 1):

Remove one select in your query

```
$res=mysql_query("Select Select YEAR (employment_date) AND MONTH(employment_date) from employee where emp_id='$userID'") or die("query error".mysql_error());
```

to

```
 $res=mysql_query("Select YEAR(employment_date) AND MONTH(employment_date) from employee where emp_id='$userID'") or die("query error".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select YEAR (employment_date) AS 'year', MONTH(employment_date) AS 'month' from employee where emp_id='$userID'"
```

hope it helps and try to use  [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this

if you want both month and year same column

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(employment_date, '%Y:%m') as employment_date from employee where emp_id='$userID'
```

(or)

if you want separate  column

```
SELECT YEAR(employment_date) AS 'year', MONTH(employment_date) AS 'month'
FROM employee Where emp_id='$userID';
```

if you want month and date only

```
  SELECT MONTH(employment_date) AS 'month', DATE(employment_date) AS 'date'
  FROM employee Where emp_id='$userID';
```

Comment: Thank you most helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDate($userID){
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT YEAR (employment_date) AS employment_year AND MONTH(employment_date) AS employment_month FROM employee WHERE emp_id='$userID'") OR die("query error".mysql_error());
 $array = mysql_fetch_array($res);
 $value_year=$array['employment_year'];
$value_month=$array['employment_year'];

 print_r($value_year . "_" . $value_month);
}
```

maybe this helps?

Comment: @Chathurika could you please select one answer? ;)